# Show that an infinite recursively enumerable subset of $\Bbb N$ must be the range of a one-to-one recursive function

Tags: logic, computability, recursion

I need to show that an infinite recursively enumerable subset of $\Bbb N$ must be the range of a one-to-one recursive function.

A theorem tells me that for a recursively enumerable set, it is either empty or the range of a recursive function.

EDIT:

I think to make it the range of a one-to-one recursive function, what I should do is trying to get a one-to one recursive function from the recursive function we obtained from the theorem I mentioned above. I think maybe I may define

Define function $g$ as:

$g(0)=f(0)$

$g(n+1)=f(min_{x\in\Bbb N} \lbrace f(x)\ne f(n) \forall n<x\rbrace)$

Then $g$ is primitive recursive and hence a recursive function . It is a total function because as $S$ is infinite, we can always find some $x$ such that $f(x)\ne f(n)\forall n<x$ and thus the minimalization is always defined.

Is that correct? Thanks advance for any help!

Comment: Are you working in a restricted computing model like primitive recursion or a more general one like turing machines?

Comment: @DanielV We do not talk about turing machine in the course, but we can write a program for computing a function to prove that it is recursive( I mean writing out a program is a vaild proof ).

Comment: In that case they probably mean general function like turing machines.  Here you have actually defined $f'$ as the inverse of a function you want to define.  I would suggest just define the function $n \mapsto \text{the } n^\text{th} \text{ value in the enumeration that isn't a repeat of a previous value}$

Comment: @DanielV If it is a possible way to do it, could you tell me how may I define the function explicity? And is it the fact that we can write some short program to compute it?

Comment: There's no such thing as "write the function explicitly" unless you have an explicitly defined computing model.  And it sounds like your teacher has been avoiding that (which is good).  It's the ideas that matter.

Comment: @DanielV I have tried the way as you said, but I think the program is problamatic(see the edited question). If possible, could you please tell me where the problem is if exists, and how to fix it?

Comment: If they mean "a recursibly enumerable infinite subset of $\mathbb N$", then you can just make a list of distinct values, and return the last value when the length of the list becomes $n + 1$.  But that only terminates because the length of the subset is infinite.  It wouldn't work on an enumeration like $2, 2, 2, 2, 2, \dots$.

Comment: @DanielV Sorry but so far I have no experience on programming and that is just a side point of the course... I editted answer and again I don't think it is correct. My knowledge on computing is too poor to write it correct... If possible, I would really appreciate if you could write it out and I would try to understand and learn how it works...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to write out an answer because I don't think that would help you.  I think you need to take more time to understand what the question is asking so that you would be able to recognize a correct or incorrect solution if you saw one.